# How to add satellite view in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

In my web application, I'm using leaflet and I want to change layer of leaflet to satellite view and other map views using layer switch. How can I perform this.Please help!

Comment: Please take a few minutes and read this: [ask]. When you're done, come back here and edit your question. Tell us what your research turned up, what solutions you've tried, what didn't work, which errors you got and what stopped you from solving it. At the moment, in it's current form this is not a question that belongs on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to be a little more specific with your questioning...that said, something like this might help.

```
var osm = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"),
    mqi = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {subdomains: ['otile1','otile2','otile3','otile4']});

var baseMaps = {
    "OpenStreetMap": osm,
    "MapQuestImagery": mqi
};

var overlays =  {//add any overlays here

    };

L.control.layers(baseMaps,overlays, {position: 'bottomleft'}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: how do I default to one? it shows nothing until I select one map layer.